Is there a Database for Relevant Information on the Hydrogen Atom to compare with the Schrodinger Equation?
simple question.
Are there any databases of information about the Hydrogen atom to compare with the Schrodinger Equation solution for it? I know there will be discrepancies but I wonder how people know that the position probability distribution of the Hydrogen atom at least somewhat follows the solution of the Schrodinger equation.
If there is a database with probability relative to phi, theta, and radius I would like to know where to find it as well as maybe an answer on how people know that the electron has a bias (both dependent and independent of time) on its location based on it's state as well as how people determine where those probabilities are.

Minor correction, I think you mean a dataset, not a database. But I think it's a good question.

I'm not sure people care about this distribution or have actually measured it extensively.  The solutions have been implicitly verified through massive corroboration of experimental data on various Zeeman, Stark regimes, through muonic and other exotic types of atoms, through transition probabilities and multiple other type of measurements.  If the solutions were incorrect we'd know by now for sure.  See also this post discussing the use of hydrogen solutions to measure the size of the proton.

@ZeroTheHero It's very interesting to me if people do not care about the distribution since to me it seems like this would be one of the first things done to corroborate the solutions of the Schrodinger equations (and the Schrodinger Equation itself) and give physical results to how the most abundant element in the universe behaves to a further extent.

Not really.  Transition rates (of various multipole transitions) are very sensitive to the shape of the wavefunctions as are angular correlations of emitted photons.  These are very well explained with the current wavefunctions so there is no real need to measure probability distributions.  There is must massive data on transitions and correlations.

Also as per link the size of the proton problem is quite sensitive to the short-distance behaviour of the wavefunctions and this is now well understood.

@ZeroTheHero When you say "current wavefunctions" do you mean an "effective" wavefunction or the most up-to-date analytical potential including for instance the Uehling potential? Are there any papers or resources you can link me of how people have verified these things about the shape or it being mentioned in such a resource?

Ueling is for 2 electric charges not hydrogen.  I don't have recent data because the topic died 75 years ago, with possibly the Lamb shift the only new thing since QED: all the fine, hyperfine, Thomas terms etc are well understood.  You can read about the size of the proton problem as a prototypical example of how the wavefunctions are used; this is highly dependent on the shape as the experiment depended on the fraction of muonic wavefunctions were "inside" the proton.

@ZeroTheHero Yes but the Uehling potential affects atomic spectra from vacuum polarization. Are you saying that there is likely not enough data to reconstruct such a thing unless a similar experiment is done or if there is periodic behavior in the Zeeman and Stark regime experiments to pull out shape information?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
